# For a knot $K\subset S^3$, the inclusion $\partial \nu K\to (S^3-\text{int}(\nu K))$ induces a surjection on $\pi_1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, knot-theory, surgery-theory

Let $K$ be a knot (embedded circle) in $S^3$ and let $M$ be obtained from $S^3$ by $0$-surgery on $K$. A meridian of $K$ in $S^3$ can be viewed as a circle $C$ in $M$. Consider the product manifold $X=S^1\times M$. $X$ contains an embedded torus $T:=S^1\times C$. Let $\nu T$ denote the closed tubular neighborhood of $T$ in $X$. How can we show that the inclusion $\partial \nu T\to X-\text{int}(\nu T)$ induces a surjection on $\pi_1$?

First, we have $\nu T=S^1\times \nu C$ where $\nu C$ is the closed tubular neighborhood of $C$ in $M$. According to this question [Perform 0-framed surgery, then remove neighbourhood of meridian. Is this the knot complement?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503617/perform-0-framed-surgery-then-remove-neighbourhood-of-meridian-is-this-the-kno), the complement of $\text{int}(\nu C)$ in $M$ is the knot complement $S^3-\text{int}(\nu K)$, where $\nu K$ is the closed tubular neighbrohood of $K$ in $S^3$. So we have  $X-\text{int}(\nu T)\cong S^1\times (S^3-\text{int}(\nu K))$. Thus we can view the inclusion  $\partial \nu T\to X-\text{int}(\nu T)$ as $S^1\times \partial \nu K\to S^1\times (S^3-\text{int}(\nu K))$. This implies that we only need to show that the inclusion $\partial \nu K\to (S^3-\text{int}(\nu K))$ induces a surjection on $\pi_1$, which I can't show. Any hints for this?

Comment: The claim (in the title of your question) is simply false for **all** nontrivial knots. Hint: Can an abelian group surject to a nonabelian one?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, I see. Maybe my argument in the second paragraph is somewhere wrong..